# Can't add raw resource type file

Tags: android, android-resources

I can't add a raw as a Resource Type while creating a new resource file. 
Anyone can help me why is that so? Picture below

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/09lYt.png

Comment: You file must finish by `.xml`

Comment: What do you mean by that? It's just new project created with xml file in it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Johanna please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on res folder -> new -> New Resource Directory -> raw

[image]

Comment: @Johanna: this is correct answer.
you should choose "Android Resource Directory" not "Android Resource File"

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are selecting "Android Resource File" while creating a raw folder.

Select "Android Resource Directory" and you will find "raw" in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Layout folder -> new -> layout resource file

and in your case you must type "raw.xml" as name not only "raw"

Answer (score 0):

because there is no raw Resource Type. Available options are
Color, Drawable, Font, Layout, Menu Transition, Values, XML

Android has raw as directory, purpose being
Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.

However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ aren't given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. It's not just write `raw.xml` as resource as someone wrote.

I used to save sqli queries on XML files and stored them in resources/raw.

But since last Gradle update, raw is no more an option to create resource files. I think it's been deprecated

I couldn't find documentation about this change.

Answer (score 0):

I kniw is too late and maybe you find already the solution but it is for another person who will have the same problem.
the solution is that you must chose New Ressource **directory**

[image]